# d3js v4 sunburst chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to map some data using [d3js zoomable sunburst][1]

[1]: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373. Following the example I did the same steps. But I think its not able to read the data correctly . Below is the code which I have so far and since its not able to read the data the output is a black circle.

https://jsfiddle.net/snt1/mbszu1u5/3/

```
 root = d3.hierarchy(root);
          root.sum(function(d) { return d.count; });
          svg.selectAll("path")
              .data(partition(root).descendants())
              .enter().append("path")
              .attr("d", arc)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name); })
              .on("click", click)
              .append("title")
              .text(function(d) { return d.data.name + "\n" + formatNumber(d.value); });
```

Comment: Just thought that it's worth mentioning that there are plenty of sunbursts in d3js 4v already working, here's one [example](https://bl.ocks.org/vasturiano/12da9071095fbd4df434e60d52d2d58d/06018245d9740366dfc13e562a74b71d53478111)

And you can find plenty more examples [here](http://blockbuilder.org/search#text%3Dsunburst%3Bd3version%3Dv4). If you're only interested in a working example